# An assignment for kids (Water in a container) leads to an optimization problem

Tags: calculus, optimization, volume

It is an assignment problem for 11-years-old kids.

> There is a water cubic container of length 10cm. The depth of water in the container is 4 cm. Three identical right circular cones are put into the container and the water level rises by 6 cm. No water flows out of the container. Find the volume of a cylinder.

Of course, this is an easy one. But I wonder whether it is possible to put three identical circular cones, each of volume $200\,\textrm{cm}^3$, into the tank so that the water does not flow out. My problem is

> Given the dimensions of a rectangular container, what is the maximum total volume of $n$ identical right circular cones can be put completely inside the container?

I have no idea for the cases of $n\ge2$.

Comment: What if $n \to \infty$ and the cylinders are infinitesimally small? Wouldn't it cover, nearly the complete volume of cube?

Comment: @JaideepKhare. I think so.

Comment: How is $n$ not always the volume which is missing from the box, in your original case $600cm^3$. You can always adjust the height and radius of the cones to be anything you want.

Comment: @Wintermute. $n$ is the number of cones. For the case of $n=3$, we cannot adjust the radii and heights so the total volume is $1000\,\textrm{cm}^3$ and the cones are completely inside the container. But I think it is difficult to see whether the total volume can be $600\,\textrm{cm}^3$.

Comment: @CYAries Sorry, misread you definition of $n$. Perhaps try a Lagrange multipliers approach.